# WorkManager no carga datos

Tags: android

Actualmente estoy tratando de sincronizar en tiempo real mi BD con WorkManager, yo opté por WorkManager ya que estoy usando Volley. El problema que estoy teniendo es que no me está mostrando el listado con todos los productos, es decir que no me muestra nada

Mi código de MainActivity es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {
ArrayList<Broches> brochesList;
GridView gridView;
EditText editText;
Adapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    brochesList = new ArrayList<>();
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    //loadBroches();
    sincronizar();
}

public void sincronizar(){
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .build();

    OneTimeWorkRequest synchronizeUsersWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UserSynchronizationWorker.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(synchronizeUsersWorkRequest);
}
```

Mi código de UserSynchronizationWorker es el siguiente:

```
public class UserSynchronizationWorker extends ListenableWorker {
private final String URL_broches = "http://192.168.43.3";
private final String endpoint = String.format("%s%s", URL_broches,"/WS/listar.php");
private final String TAG = "synchronization";
private final String NAME = UserSynchronizationWorker.class.getSimpleName();
private final String errorMessage = "Error al sincronizar";

private final Executor executor;
private final RequestQueue requestQueue;
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

/**
 * @param appContext   The application {@link Context}
 * @param workerParams Parameters to setup the internal state of this worker
 */
public UserSynchronizationWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(appContext, workerParams);
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(appContext);
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture( completer->{
        SynchronizationCallback callback = new SynchronizationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(SynchronizationException exception) {
                completer.set(Result.failure());
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                List<Broches> broches = read(jsonArray);
                broches.forEach(System.out::println);
                completer.set(Result.success());
            }
        };
        completer.addCancellationListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(requestQueue != null){
                    requestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);
                }
            }
        }, executor);

        getUsers(callback);
        return callback;
    });



}

private void getUsers(SynchronizationCallback callback) {
    JsonArrayRequest  jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, endpoint, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            callback.onResponse(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            callback.onFailure(new SynchronizationException(errorMessage, error));
        }
    });

    jsonArrayRequest.setTag(TAG);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private List<Broches> read(JSONArray jsonArray){
    try{
        return Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(jsonArray.toString(), Broches[].class));
    }catch (IOException exc){
        throw new SynchronizationException(errorMessage, exc);
    }
}
```

}

Hice Log.d de la variable broches y la variable jsonarrayrequest, las cuales están en la clase UserSynchronizationWorker y no entra al Log, es decir que no me muestra que es lo que hay en esas dos variables

Comment: Recuerda revisar el LogCat, puedes acceder al EndPoint http://192.168.43.3/WS/listar.php ?

Comment: Pero, una pregunta, ¿qué entiendes realmente por *sincronizar en tiempo real*?

Comment: @Jorgesys hice Log.d del endpoint, pero no aparece en el LogCat

Comment: @A.Cedano Yo lo que entiendo por eso es que cuando se actualicen los datos de la BD, lo que está en la tablet también debe actualizarse

Comment: @A. Cedano, no se si me explico con lo que quise decir

Comment: Ya, pero, ¿actualizarse dónde exactamente? Supongo que quieres sincronizar entre la base de datos remota (para la cual usas Volley) y una base de datos que tienes en local en el dispositivo (para lo cual se recomienda actualmente usar Room).

Comment: Quiero sincronizar entre la BD remota y la del dispositivo

Comment: ¿Ya tienes creada la BD en el dispositivo? ¿Qué tipo de sincronización: unidireccional o bidireccional? Te advierto que estás ante uno de los procesos más complejos de Android. [Aquí tienes una guía completa que convendría leer](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide).